# What will the changes when I changed my replication factor manually?

Tags: hadoop2

What will happen when I changed my replication factor manually from 3 to 4 , Is there any changes in past data and what about the replications from the changes made?

Please provide me all possible solutions.

Comment: ur data will not get effect if you have not changed the db path. it will just effect the db performance

Comment: Accept the answer if your query has been answered

Answer (score 0):

If you change the Replication factor manually, then it will be fixed for the upcoming data in your cluster. It won't change the replication factor of the old data.

Suppose, you had a data with 3 replicas and now you decide to change the replication to 4, then the old data will remain to have 3 replicas but any new data you ingest will get a replication of 4.

Now, if you also want to change the replication of your old data then you have to do it manually. For that, Hadoop provides a command:

> hdfs dfs -setrep -w [replication_factor] [/dir/path]